# problem with creating textures

Tags: texturing

I'm learning how to use Blender through numerous tutorials. Today, I came to a point where I'm not sure if there is something wrong with the version (2.77) of the program, or if I'm doing something incorrect. I will attach a screenshot (on the left is shot of the documentation I'm reading and on the right is the Blender window). I'm asking about the missing *Properties panel > Textures tab* options.

Could someone help me find them?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: cycles and blender internal have different settings for setting the materials. you are using cycles as the render and the documentation on the left are for setting a material in blender internal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first issue is the use of *Cycles Render* in the top options bar. Change to *Blender Render*.

Once you do, change where it says *Environment Textures* to the materials button, as seen in the documentation.

Comment: @Dominika if my answer helped, please consider accepting it by clicking the checkmark in the upper left-hand corner of my answer.